# Little Schemer Curry Example in Ruby

Tags: ruby, proc, the-little-schemer

I'm trying to implement currying as per the the Little Schemer example `eq?` given below. `eq( test, testFor)` takes in a test condition and an atom and returns a function based on the passed function `test`, which takes one argument to return a boolean.

Here is my code:

```
def eq( test, s)
    Proc.new { |x| test(s,x)}
end

eqToCarrot = eq(Proc.new{|x,y| x==y},"carrot")

if eqToCarrot.call("carrot")
    puts "Equal!"
end
```

The if condition is not executed. Can someone tell me why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To call `test` within your `eq method`, you need to use `test.call` instead of just `test`.

As is, the reason you're not getting an `Undefined method` or other error from your `test(..)` expression in `eq` is that there is a Kernel method named `test` which accepts 2 or 3 parameters.

To answer the question in your comment about how to return a proc which returns a proc, you "just do it". For example, you can return `Proc.new {Proc.new {puts 'foo'}}`.

And since proc variables can be passed around and returned like any other variable without concern for them being accidentally "invoked", if you pass in a proc variable as an argument, you can simply return that variable, as in `Proc.new {|proc| proc}`.

In your case, though, if you're trying to create a predicate based on an argument passed in, you can do the following:

```
def make_eq_proc(match_string)
  Proc.new {|arg_string| arg_string == match_string}
end

eq_carrot = make_eq_proc('carrot')

eq_carrot.call('carrot') # => true
```

Comment: so how does a function return a proc which returns a proc?

Comment: I can't answer now, but if no one else gets back to you, I'll reply in a couple of hours.

Comment: Actually I wanted to pass in the predicate as a proc also, is that possible?

Comment: @AmanGupta Sure. I'm a little lost, though, in terms of which proc in your "proc which returns a proc" accepts the predicate as a parameter.  What are the method signatures of your two procs and the method signature of the predicate you want to pass in?

Comment: okay basically I want a function that takes in a predicate ( a function that returns a bool) and an argument and returns a function that takes an argument that applies the predicate to the original argument. Am I being clear enough?

Comment: @AmanGupta Almost. :-)  Does the predicate take two parameters - the original argument and the argument passed in to the function being returned?

Comment: @AmanGupta Ok, what you just described matches your original definition of `eq`, modified to use `test.call` instead of `test`. But that's just a function that takes a proc and returns a proc that returns a boolean (resulting from an invocation of a predicate). That's not the same as returning a proc that returns a proc.